# Ember / Handlebars: How to write the attribute string

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

For example:

```
<img src="{{profile.avatar}}"/>
```

Do I really have  to create a helper for this or is it possible to write the attribute string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `bind-attr`-helper for this. `bindAttr` will also work but is deprecated since [1.0 RC8](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html) as pointed out by intuitivepixel.

```
<img {{bind-attr src=profile.avatar}}/>
```

More info is available in their [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/).

Comment: Great, it works. And thanks for the link, I knew I saw this somewhere but couldn't find it again.

Comment: Note that you can also use `<img src="{{unbound profile.avatar}}"/>` if the property is not going to change before the view is re-rendered. This saves a bit of memory by avoiding the binding.

Comment: also worth mentioning is that `bindAttr` is deprecated in favor of `bind-attr`

Comment: Good point, I've updated my answer to use `bind-attr` with a note about the deprecation of `bindAttr`.

Answer (score 1):

For Ember newcomers (whom came to this question by Googleling for example), since Ember 1.11 and later, you should write:

```
<img src="{{profile.avatar}}"/>
```

Just as OP wrote in his question!

---

**Note**:
Since Ember 1.13 the `bind-attr` helper has been deprecated.